# Mongoose - Array being saved as string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my schema file I'm trying to set the type property to be an array. As seen here

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const model = mongoose.Schema({
    _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    "type" : Array,
})

export const Stocks = mongoose.model("stocks", model)
```

Although for some reason, when I try to save the document it saves the document as a string even if its an element in an array it still returns a string. This is my code for saving the document;

```js
export async function sendStock(data) {
    if (!data) throw new Error("Missing Stock API Data")

    let stock = {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        "type": [ data["put_call"] ],
    }

    Stocks.findOne({"ticker": stock.ticker}, (err, res) => {
        if (!res) return new Stocks(stock).save();
  })
}
```

This is the mongoose schema viewed in the website
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TACoo.png

I'm not the best at mongoose but, I'm sure something is up but I'm not saving the document any where else but still save a string.

Comment: Try use [String] and not Array when you declare the variable in the schema. i.e. type: [String]

Comment: Have you tried replacing Array in your model with mongoose.Schema.Types.Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model should be like this

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const model = mongoose.Schema({
    _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    type : [String], //<=== I'm assuming you are receiving string array
})

export const Stocks = mongoose.model("stocks", model)
```

Also you might want to format the value you are saving as if it's not coming in as an `array` it will fail.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Also, could you explain formatting?

Comment: The way you are adding data `[ data["put_call"] ]` is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const model = mongoose.Schema({
    _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    type : { type: []},
})

export const Stocks = mongoose.model("stocks", model)
```